# updating an already existing iOS App

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

I am facing a problem working on an iOS App for a client. I have created a new version of the client's app as he requested and he seems very happy with it. Now I have to publish it on the App Store, the only problem is the app has to be updated to a newer version. The previous developer had published the app using his own provisioning profile and refuses to share any code or the provisioning profile now. To make it more precise I don't have the client's certificate, private key, and the correct provisioning profile used to originally launch the app on the app store. If I create a completely new version of the app and even somehow manage to have the previous developer delete the old app from the app store, the client looses a lot of app's users.

Can you guys please advise what is the best way to sort this mess? Many Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to the account on which the previous app was posted?

Comment: @rckoenes sadly no, otherwise it would've been a lot more easier.

Comment: If you have previos developer's machine handy then you can grab required private keys and certificate from keychain.

Comment: @AppleDeveloper read the post, he can't access the pricvate keys of certificates.

Comment: That's weird situation! AFAIK Without having access to account you can't update App!!

Comment: @AppleDeveloper I wish I had access to his machine.

Comment: Well if you dont have acces to the account under which the app is posted you will not be able to update that app. Since you will need to sign in with the account that posted that app. You cannot acces app posted under other accounts.

Comment: The original author own the copyrights to the app as well unless the rights were specifically transferred to the client so look out if he wants to get ugly if you are using anything from his previous app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need acces to the account which published the app. Once you have acces just create new certificates and provisioning profiles.

If you do not have access to that account there is no way you can update that app.